# KeyCode_Enter to next edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, setfocus

In edittext, after typing 'Enter' key, system make a new line inside it. I'd like to focus on next edittext, no new line. how to code? my code in xml is below

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtNPCode"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblNPCode"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblNPCode"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtCNPCode"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblCNPCode"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblCNPCode"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

I also caputer key code in setOnKeyListener

```
   tCNPCode.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(keyCode == 66) {
                Toast.makeText(S_PCode.this, "Enter Key", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //tNPCode.setFocusable(true);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to use the [`requestFocus`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus%28%29) method. In your case it will be something like:

```
tCNPCode.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            txtCNPCode.requestFocus();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I use requestFocus. It worked. need to add return true;?

Comment: I would suggest to filter it with ACTION_UP as well because you'll hit the onKey method twice and if you are implementing the setOnKeyListener to a list of EditTexts inside an ArrayList<EditText>, you will risk going two steps forward.

if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)

Comment: I wouldnt use the actual int literal, as its not readable at all.

Answer (score 38):

You don't even have to use `OnKeyListener`. Simply add line `android:singleLine="true"` to your `EditText`. After this operation `EditText` behaves exactly like you want. So, in your particular case:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtNPCode"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblNPCode"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblNPCode"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtCNPCode"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblCNPCode"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblCNPCode"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
/>
```

solves the problem.

Comment: This id fine, But the android:singleLine="true" is deprecated.

Answer (score 10):

The best way is to use one of the options for inputType, for example: `android:inputType="textPersonName"`
This will achieve the wanted effect. Check out the other options too, it'll save you some time in future :)

You shouldn't use android:singleLine="true", since it's deprecated. Here's what the documentations says about it:

> This attribute is deprecated and is replaced by the textMultiLine 
>    flag in the inputType attribute. Use caution when altering existing 
>    layouts, as the default value of singeLine is false (multi-line 
>    mode), but if you specify any value for inputType, the default is 
>    single-line mode. (If both singleLine and inputType attributes are 
>    found, the inputType flags will override the value of singleLine.).

Answer (score 10):

Consider IME options, good description here http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=C824437B48F346E23FBE5828969029B4?recipeId=422 and documentation here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions.

The only thing you need is add attribute android:imeOptions="actionNext" on each EditText. Keyboard appears with a Next key where Enter used to be and allows to navigate to the next EditText.

But order of "actionNext" is from top to bottom. For example, if you have horizontal layout:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <EditText android:id="@+id/et1" android:imeOptions="actionNext" />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/et2" android:imeOptions="actionNext" />
</LinearLayout>
```

et2 never get focus. You should fix it in the code:

```
et1.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
            KeyEvent event)
    {
        switch (actionId)
        {
        case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT:
            boolean result = false;
            TextView v1 = (TextView) v.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
            if (v1 != null)
                result = v1.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
            else if (!result)
            {
                v1 = (TextView) v.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                if (v1 != null)
                    result = v1.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            }
            if (!result)
                v.onEditorAction(actionId);
            break;

        default:
            v.onEditorAction(actionId);
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Original link: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/OykOG6XtE8w

Answer (score 2):

> **Use Single Line of Code (Java)**

```
tCNPCode.setSingleLine(true);
```

> **Kotlin**

```
tCNPCode.isSingleLine = true
```

It will navigate to the next item on Enter press

Answer (score 1):

Just set the maximum number of line to the `EditText` box in xml layout file: 
`android:maxLength="1"`