# Transfer focus in next edit text automatically

Tags: java, android

How to Transfer focus in next edit text automatically when first edit text input is greater then 4 digits? And  how to go back again on first edit text when next edit text data is deleted?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019965/keycode-enter-to-next-edittext

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I would recommend showing any research you have done as well as any attempts you have made to solve your problem.  You will be a whole lot more likely to receive responses if you do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
edittext1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
        int count) {

        if(editText.getText().toString().Length()>=4)
           {
              editText2.requestFocus();
           }
}
});
```