# how to go on next edit text when i press enter

Tags: android

```
EditText nameedit = new EditText(this);
    nameedit.setHint("First name");
    blur.addView(nameedit);
    nameedit.setWidth(32);
      nameedit.setEms(50);
    MarginLayoutParams params3 = (MarginLayoutParams) nameedit.getLayoutParams();
     params3.leftMargin = 16; params3.topMargin = 125;
    nameedit.setLayoutParams(params3);
    Typeface font33=Typeface.SERIF;
    nameedit.setTypeface(font33);
```

here when i press enter my edit text will become longer rether than go to next edittext view.....
i want to gone on next edit text view when i press enter....*

Comment: This post seems to answer your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019965/keycode-enter-to-next-edittext

Comment: You have to handle that explicitly. You need to handle key presses and then determine what to do with them. @kevinrmannix post does just that.

Comment: Have you checked out the `imeOptions` attribute? There is the possibility to set `actionNext`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're creating the EditText programmatically. You just need to set the IME options with the [`setImeOptions()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setImeOptions%28int%29) method. Since (as I understand it) you do not want to allow multiple lines, you should also [`setMaxLines()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMaxLines%28int%29).

In this case it would be:

```
edit.setMaxLines(1);
edit.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
```

Answer (score 9):

There is an attribute of EditText in xml for this purpose.

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

This will add "Next" button on your soft Keyboard for going to the next EditText.

Answer (score 6):

If you place `android:singleLine="true"` on your `EditText` it will automatically change the **Enter** button on your keyboard into a **Next** button.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it programmaticaly, my solution in most cases is:

```
editText.setSingleLine(true);
```

Or just add this in your xml item

```
android:singleLine="true"
```