# setOnKeyListener on EditText is not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have applied setOnKeyListener on editText in my activity, but it does not invoke this method when I press any key on keyboard.

I want to detect if space or enter is pressed on keyboard, but I did not find any way to find out these key codes.

I have tried TextWatcher also but it does not tell us the keycode which I want.

Please help me if anybody know how can we do this.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Please paste your code snippet? Also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019965/keycode-enter-to-next-edittext

Comment: In your TextWatcher get the text from EditText and then check the string for space.

Answer (score 0):

```
//You should try 

edittext..addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: I down vote this as he has already mentioned about using TextWatcher.

Answer (score -1):

You can detect Enter key pressed as below.

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    // Perform action on key press
                    Log.e("Value", "Enter");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;


            }
        });
```