# When Pressing "Enter" button on EditText is creating a new line

Tags: android, android-edittext

When I'm pressing "enter" on the keyboard, the EditText space is creating a new line and raising the space of EditText, disturbing my app layout. How can I stop this?

Thanks!

Comment: You could set the EditText to single line in the XML. What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: Are you looking for this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019965/keycode-enter-to-next-edittext

Comment: [use-enter-key-on-softkeyboard-instead-of-clicking-button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451374/use-enter-key-on-softkeyboard-instead-of-clicking-button)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These 3 flags will solve your issue. Add them to your edit text view.

```
android:inputType="text"
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Got it!

Comment: Glad I could help. If this is the correct answer then please mark it as correct (and upvote) so future people will know. what the solution was.

Answer (score 3):

Try this when using  `TextInputEditText`

```
android:inputType="text"
android:maxLines="1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set the attribute inputType of the EditText to text like

```
android:inputType="text"
```